# Initialize a variable with nil vs implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: swift

In Swift Guide https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html
there is an example of using Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals

```
class Country {
    let name: String
    var capitalCity: City!
    init(name: String, capitalName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
}

class City {
    let name: String
    unowned let country: Country
    init(name: String, country: Country) {
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
}
```

And I am wondering if it is possible and what difference it would make if I made a small change:

```
var capitalCity: City = nil
```

Comment: That small change won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will simply not compile. Here's why.

By specifying `var capitalCity: City`, you're explicitly saying that your variable is **non-optional**. It can only ever hold a valid `City`. It can never be optional, so it can never hold `nil`.

Meanwhile, anytime you use `?` or `!`, you are defining an optional type. These **can** be nil, and in fact are `nil` by default.

So in your example from the guide, `var capitalCity: City!` is saying the following:

- `capitalCity` is declared as an *implicitly unwrapped optional* type (the `!`), meaning that you, as the developer, are declaring it to always have a valid `City` type whenever it is called.
- That said, until you set a `City` to it, it defaults to being `nil`.

When you should use optionals comes down to how you want to use your properties. In the original example, from what little we see, `capitalCity` is only set in the class init. So there wouldn't be a reason for it to be optional. So for that example, it could exist like the other property: `let capitalCity: City`.

A lot depends on how you want the properties to exist and work when you're using your object. For instance, making something optional signals at least two things:

1. The property may not have a valid value in the class' lifecycle.
2. You may not be setting it when you initialize your class. (Remember, an optional initializes to `nil`)

I hope this helps you understand optionals some more.

Comment: You should mention that there is no reason to make `capitalCity` optional at all since it is properly initialized to a non-nil value in the initializer.

Comment: In this context, I agree. I was directly answering his question about what the difference would be between what was in the guide and what he wanted to do. I can make a note about that, though. Thanks, @rmaddy.

Comment: That's right, thanks! But I think what I meant was actually var capitalCity: City? = nil

Comment: @rmaddy The reason for making it optional is I think that the initializer for City is called from within the initializer for Country. However, the initializer for Country cannot pass self to the City initializer until a new Country instance is fully initialized

Comment: @EasySkankin I did overlook the fact that you need to pass `self` to the `City` initializer in the `Country` initializer. That does change things.